# Nested References in Excel

Tags: excel, reference, nested

I'm working on a three sheet Excel spreadsheet that needs to be "idiot-proof" (Someone chooses an option from a drop-down menu and the formula fills itself in).

So in the first sheet, there are lists of ratios that are used to look things up in tables located in the second sheet; the locations those tables are associated with the drop-down list.

Here's where it gets fun:  the new piece I'm adding in the second sheet has 5 tables associated with it.  So one ratio from the first sheet picks the table, and another one is used to interpolate on that table.  The third sheet is being used to store the calculated table location - Match() is used to pick the table, nested if statements to get the row number associated with it.  I used Address() to get the actual location in sheet 2 listed in sheet 3.

I need an array in my interpolation function, being in the first sheet.  I've been trying anything to get the same result using formulas as if I went to sheet 2 and physically selected the boxes I need.  What looks most promising so far is Index().
D31 in sheet 3 contains the address of the upper left of the table in Sheet 2, and G31 has the bottom right.
INDEX(Sheet3!$D$31:Sheet3!$G$31,0,1)
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/index-function-HP010342608.aspx

The thing is, this is giving me the items in Sheet 3 as the array, and still not letting me access Sheet 2 from that.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I've run completely out.  Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem here.. What **exactly** is not working?

Comment: The nested reference.  The array I need isn't coming in, instead it is listing an array from the sheet that's holding the location of the array I need.  Sorry, I'm not sure how else to phrase it.  Does that make any more sense?

Comment: If I understand properly, you are saying that it is not pointing to the proper Sheet/Cell? Yes it already makes more sense, thanks. But now I don't understand why you use a third table to store cell Ranges of your tables instead of just referencing them in your Sheet 1?

Comment: For different rows in Sheet 1, it will be looking at a different section in Sheet 2.  There is a calculation required to determine the section of Sheet 2 being used, so I'm using Sheet 3 to make that calculation to make it a fully automated workbook.